# Parsing value from JSON string fails

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to extract the value of `entry` from below string. I tried to parse the string with `json.loads()` but it doesn't work. Instead, I receive below error message.

This is the string:

```
output = '336,{"token":"eyJhbGc.iOiJIUzI18_YREPr50","entry":"961156ef-2a9","project":"86a8e55a-9160","tenant":["73426ca1-bde"]}'
```

This is my code:

```
entry_id = json.loads(output)["entry"]
```

This is the error message:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
   return _default_decoder.decode(s)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 367, in decode
   raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 4 - line 1 column 341 (char 3 - 340)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Only the `{...}`-part is the JSON object you can extract that value from. You need to split the string before you parse. (You should add the optional `maxsplit` argument to only split on the first comma.)

Example:

```
x, s = output.split(',', 1)
entry_id = json.loads(s)["entry"]
```

The number before that comma is in itself a valid JSON value, but comma separated values are only allowed inside JSON arrays `[...]` or JSON objects `{...}`. The error message therefore indicates, that there is extra data in the input string that doesn't belong there. Therefore you need to strip the value before you can parse the object contained in the remainder of the string.

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split
- http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

First remove the first 4 characters to get a valid JSON string and then use `json.loads()` to get value from JSON string.

```
# remove first four characters
line = output[4:]
# parse a value from json to get id
entry_id = json.loads(line)["entry"]
print entry
```

Output:

```
961156ef-2a9
```